# Crystal Report 2011 Report/SQL Server 2008/ASPX Issues

Tags: coldfusion, crystal-reports, coldfusion-10

I have a webserver configured with ColdFusion 10.  Within an application I have built in ColdFusion, I want to deploy a Crystal Report that requires a parameter that the user would enter.  I built the report in Crystal Reports 2011.  The report works within the Designer.

I then used Recrystallize to generate the ASPX, ASPX.VB, and Web.config pages that go with the report.

I had to adjust the IIS settings to accommodate the fact that ColdFusion requires the enabling of 32 bit applications and the Crystal Reports components require the disabling of 32 bit applications by putting the Crystal Report and pages in their own folder, converting them to an application and setting that application to a different Application Pool than the ColdFusion application.

The report viewer initially opened with the prompt for the parameter that the report was built on.  When you entered the parameter and clicked OK, the report would error with a dialog of:  Failed to open the connection.  Failed to open the connection.  [with the report name].

I am not sure where to begin troubleshooting this.

Any help that you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To add to this description of the issue. If I create a static report and publish the report with Recrystallize, it will publish without issue.  Also, I have ensured that the ODBC connector on my laptop is the same as the connector on the webserver (i.e. SQL Server Native Client 10).  The name is the same.  I thought that it could be if one connector was setup as sqlservername\sqlserverinstance versus IP address of sqlserver\sqlserverinstance, but that did not have any impact.

Comment: Does your ODBC datasource on the webserver verify/test okay?  Is it able to connect from the datasource configuration.

Answer (score 0):

this is aspx file.....

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updpnlReport" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="crvAccountReportParameter" runat="server"             
                oninit="crvAccountReportParameter_Init" 
                EnableParameterPrompt="False" HasToggleParameterPanelButton = "false" HasCrystalLogo ="False"/>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This is .cs fie..........

```
   protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadData();

    }
    protected void LoadData()
    {

        string pstrType;
        pstrType = Request.QueryString["Type"];

        string strCompanyName = objSession.SelCompanyName;
        string strBranchName = objSession.SelBranchName;

        string strHeading = "";       
        DataSet dsData = null;

        dsData = objAccountReportBAL.getAccountRegister(Convert.ToInt16(objSession.FyId), int.MinValue, long.MinValue, Convert.ToDateTime(RadDtpFromDate.SelectedDate), Convert.ToDateTime(RadDtpToDate.SelectedDate), pstrType);
        dsData.Tables[0].TableName = "Account_Trn_v";

        if (pstrType == "JV")
        {
            strHeading = "Journal Voucher Register Report";
            rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/ReportCrystal/Account/Detail/GeneralVoucharRegister.rpt"));
        }


        rptDoc.SetDataSource(dsData.Tables[0]);

        rptDoc.SetParameterValue("@CompanyName", objSession.SelCompanyName);
        rptDoc.SetParameterValue("@BranchName", objSession.SelBranchName);
        rptDoc.SetParameterValue("@Heading", strHeading);
        rptDoc.SetParameterValue("@Stdate", RadDtpFromDate.SelectedDate);
        rptDoc.SetParameterValue("@EnDate", RadDtpToDate.SelectedDate);

        crvAccountReportParameter.ReportSource = rptDoc;         
        crvAccountReportParameter.DataBind();      

    }
```

Comment: I hate to be so dense, but where in the ASPX file would that code go and I don't have a CS file to enter that code into.  I have a ASPX file, ASPX.VB file, and the RPT file.